# how to collect static files and upload them s3 using django, Lambda and zappa

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using `django` and `zappa` (https://github.com/zappa/Zappa). I am trying to collect the static file of django and upload it to s3 and after running the command `python manage.py collectstatic --no-input` for some reason i keep getting these errors:

```
...raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessControlListNotSupported) when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket does not allow ACLs

...
  raise err_cls("S3Storage error at {!r}: {}".format(name, force_str(ex)))
OSError: S3Storage error at 'admin/css/widgets.css': An error occurred (AccessControlListNotSupported) when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket does not allow ACLs
```

I have the following configuration:

## settings.py

(i am using `django_s3_storage`)

```
DEBUG=False
...

S3_BUCKET = "my-bucket"

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage"

AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC = S3_BUCKET

STATIC_URL = "https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/" % S3_BUCKET

STATIC_ROOT = "https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/" % S3_BUCKET

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
```

the current aws user, is part of the `group admin` of users that i have created, which has `administratorAccess` policy and on top of that i have created the policy below that i have attached to the same group:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:CreateMultipartUpload",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, i made sure to uncheck all `block public access` from the bucket permissions

[image]

Not sure what to do at this point, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears you have enabled a fairly new feature on your bucket that disables object ACLs: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-s3-object-ownership-simplify-access-management-data-s3/

Comment: @MarkB any recommendation on how to solve this besides the article?

Comment: It's pretty clear you need to disable that setting on the S3 bucket.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? How can you deactivate this?