# How to upload media files to AWS S3 within Django app without getting a ClientError

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm getting the following error when I try to upload images within the admin panel,

```
An error occurred (AccessControlListNotSupported) when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket does not allow ACLs
```

I've setup the settings.py file and AWS according to the django-storages docs, but still not working.

All Static files are being imported in and can be read

Also tried changing the `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL` to 'none' and 'public-read-write' but still not working.

settings.py config:

```
if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = public-read
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    #Additional settings
    AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_STATIC_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myproject.storages.StaticStore'
    # s3 media settings
    AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproject.storages.MediaStore'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

AWS Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70553297

Answer (score 0):

This may be a stretch, but try the following IAM role, notice I removed the delimiter from statement2 resource to `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leeroy, I've tried multiple paths and didn't work. Just managed to get it working, as the problem was related to the AWS_DEFAULT_ACL I removed it from my settings.py and all started to work. Its very odd as none of the recommanded settings were didn't work.